# Responsive grid without streching

Tags: html, css, grid

I would like to create a grid with as many elements as possible in its width but without stretching the grid elements to fit 100% of the window.
So I'm using CSS grid with `auto fill` which works almost as I'd like.
I would like my grid elements not to be stretched to fill the whole page (so they have a static width), but to always have the same width, and if there is not enough space for a grid element, fill it with white space to the right (instead of stretching them so it fits 100% of the window).

here is my code:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(10em, 1fr));
  }

  .cadres {
    background-color: red;
  }
.cadres:nth-child(2n+1){

  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cadres">
      a
      </div>
    <div class="cadres">
      b
      </div>
    <div class="cadres">c</div>
    <div class="cadres">d</div>
    <div class="cadres">e</div>
  </div>
```

What I would like :

[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: replace `minmax(10em, 1fr)` with `10em` ?

Answer (score 1):

**I know this is late, but for anyone else with this problem who would prefer to stick to grid rather than flex:**

I ran into a similar issue where I used grid to align a few boxes of text but they would all stretch if one of them grew due to their content

I found using *align-self:* was the solution for me. By aligning the box that was growing to *start* then it would no longer stretch for the other one.

I found my solution here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex box` for this. Change `display: grid;` to `display: flex` and add `flex-wrap: wrap;`. With this, when your inner `div` will be too large to fit the remaining space, they will be shifted to the bottom row.

Here is the documentation of [Flex Box](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Here is the example:

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cadres {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5px;
}

.cadres:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cadres">
      a
    </div>
    <div class="cadres">
      b
    </div>
    <div class="cadres">c</div>
    <div class="cadres">d</div>
    <div class="cadres">e</div>
  </div>
```